# Does Stargate REST API support Cassandra batch query?

Tags: cassandra, stargate-oss

Does Stargate rest api support batch query in Cassandra (DSE 6.8)? If any, can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 3):

Batch queries are not supported at this time but we do have the following issue for adding the functionality

https://github.com/stargate/stargate/issues/821